# Server name is showing as www.google.com while recording in JMeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, load-testing, mobile-application

I am trying to do load testing on mobile app using JMeter.

While recording the request in JMeter, the server name is being recorded as www.google.com as shown below:

[image]

I am not sure why this is happening; I am trying to test an android application, which I have downloaded from play store.

Is it correct behavior? Or am I missing something.

Comment: It seems like you're not able to record your application's request because of SSL certificate error. please confirm your application URL, its http or https?, and if https then you need to implement Jmeter CA certificate in your device (Which is now not supported in android 7/nougat onwards),

Comment: Hi Yugal thanks for the help. I am testing in android 10. it is a native application. it is https. In this case do I need to test in lesser version of android. Is there any other way

Comment: Yes, you can use android emulators like genymotion which can provide lower version of android. if you know your application request's behaviour then its better to create your http request in jmeter manully.

Comment: I have tried creating http request manually but how will I know that it is testing the mobile app api not desktop browser api. However I know that it will hit the same server, but if you can throw some light on this it would be really helpful

Comment: You need to intercept your apis from your mobile device, which will require a proxy tool with CA certificate in place(e.g. fiddler, burpsuite, charls proxy or jmeter if recording) that will give you insight on what apis being used by your application. but to my knowledge you can intercept your device only with lower version of android before nougat or rooted devices. 

reference: https://portswigger.net/support/installing-burp-suites-ca-certificate-in-an-android-device

Comment: thanks alot Yugal, one last clarification if I have api urls doesnot matter If i am recording or not I can do the load testing as is in Jmeter. It will serve the purpose of doing load testing on my native app

Comment: Yes, It serves the purpose, but you need to know the behaviour of users using the app, e.g. what is usage distribution of APIs being used and that needs to be simulated using "throughput controller" in your load testing.